# Unity / Compiz problem after update from Xorg ppa

Tags: unity, compiz, xorg, ppa

After update from Xorg ppa (ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa)
I have many problems with Unity Shell / Compiz.
Preview of moving icons is broken and GTK theme of unselected windows breaks.

Video:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BArR1OsssD0

Video card: Intel GMA965
System: Ubuntu 11.04
Kernel: 2.6.39-3 - present
My old Kernels: 2.6.38-8 - the same problem
2.6.38-10 - the same problem

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1):

As you have found, the edgers PPA can be very unstable - it is frequently updated.  Some updates are OK - some will break your system.

My general advice would be - if you find that a particular update from edgers work for you, then untick the box in software sources for the edgers PPA, so no further updates are received which can break your system.

I note that you are using both the edgers PPA and Kernel 2.6.39-3.  Can I ask why?

You perhaps can either wait for a few days to see if a further update to edgers works - or you can ppa_purge the edgers PPA to return to a known Natty build configuration.

If you want to do a ppa_purge, then in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge

sudo ppa-purge xorg-edgers
```

You may have to also boot from the standard Natty kernel, 2.6.38.x